# Rails / PostgreSQL - Select timestamp between two times - Converted to a certain timezone (i.e. "-05:00")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, timezone, timestamp, between

I have a `timestamp` type in my PostgreSQL. (without timezone)
This `timestamp` is saved by default as UTC time.

I would like to select a number of records that:

1. Is between (time1)...(time2)
2. Such that, time1 and time2 are values given in EST time. For example, time1 == Jan-10th 10pm EST (which == Jan-11th 3am UTC)

I know that I could use a combination of `BETWEEN` and `AT TIME ZONE`. Either which I individually use in different queries, kind of like such:

`timestamp::TIMESTAMPTZ AT TIME ZONE '-05:00'`

`"timestamp" BETWEEN '2016-01-13 00:00:00.000000' AND '2016-01-14 00:00:00.000000'`

But I just don't know how to use them together in the same query - pardon my Noobness in SQL queries in general.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use ActiveSupport and Active record to do something along the lines of

```
Object.where(created_at: Time.new(2016, 01, 13, 1, 1, 1, '-05:00')..Time.new(2016, 01, 14, 1, 1, 1, '-05:00'))
```

Then you can use the TimeWithZone http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-c-new for any timezone modifications. Then ActiveSupport and ActiveRecord will handle all the weirdness for you.